# Given AB=BA then A is diagonizable iff B is diagonalizable.(True/False)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n $ matrices in $\mathbb{M_n}($$\mathbb{R}$) such that $AB=BA$ ,then prove or disprove

> $A$ is diagonizable over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $B$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$

Solution Ii tried - Given that $A$ is diagonalizable then it implies $$A=PDP^{-1},$$where $P$ is an invertible matrix.Now by using this we have to prove that $B$ is also diagonalizable (don't know whether this is true or false )

I am stuck here how to use this information to prove or disprove this statement.

Please Help

Thankyou.

Comment: Start by considering the special case where $A$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$AI=IA$. If the statement is true then every matrix would be diagonalizable (because $I$ is).

Comment: I don't think about this ,Thankyou sir,but if we want to solve this question without taking $B=I$ .

Comment: @gauravsaini How about $B=0$?

Comment: @gauravsaini Then try $B = 2I$? What makes an answer invalid here?

Comment: Two downvotes? Can someone tell me what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Ok Sir got it ,only one example is sufficent to disprove the sattement. and yes answer is false according to answer key.